# Parent div also drag when child div drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a parent div which is draggable, in this parent div i have another div which is also draggable. When i am dragging child div parent div also drag. 
Problem:- How I drag child div in parent div without moving parent div.

For example:-

```
 <div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    abc
    </div>
 </div>

        $( "#parent" ).draggable({ });
    $( "#child" ).draggable({ containment: "#parent"});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a live demo? [I can't](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls22xbka/).

Comment: Here is your code in a fiddle but works as expected - http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/dyj803x5/

Comment: I am using this in gridster. Wait i will show you on test server

Comment: Here is the url:-  http://www.drugtestingmanagement.com/dtmsec/76east/prototype.php?uid=D6F57173-02D3-4609-B116-F0D7829B5191&sid=6CAB14A2-5911-4C6E-95F2-09AFED52886E      first click on 'B',Click on 'Add Table', Enter number of Rows and Columns, Click on 'Add Tables', Click on screen to add table, Now click on 'Add Button', Change some CSS of button, Now click on 'Add Button', Now click on Table, Now when you drag button then you can see table also drags.

Comment: I want to drag button only on table, But when i drag then table also drag. You can find this line for button drag event on line 473        code:- $( "#"+globalIdTosetRow ).draggable({ containment: "parent"

Comment: scrap my answer, watching the code it looks like the button is part of the gridster grid but really it isn't as it is part of the div with is part of the grid, when the it is being dragged around it is effecting the main grid

Comment: @Quince Yes, Button is the part of the gridster now. So how we drag  button in a grid?

Comment: but from what it looks like where the table is it is not a second nested gridster. I found an example while looking (http://jsfiddle.net/YS4Ce/) for nested gridsters that shows what i think your desired result is but they clearly have one nested in another where as yours is just two elements inside the same div not two seperate grids (at least that is what it looks like)

Comment: This is look like, But this is not my client requirement. He want to show button only in grid over anywhere on table.

Comment: Then I would say do not make the button a gridster element just a plain draggable.

Comment: But i am saving gridster serialized data, So i need to insert my all content in gridster.

Answer (score 0):

you just use this code

```
$( "#child" ).draggable({ containment: "#parent"});
```

and set width and height for #parent div